# TeX in EPUB file is shrunk on e-reader

Tags: formatting, fontsize, mathjax, resize

Here is what my EPUB file looks like in Calibre:

[image]

and here is what I see on my newly purchased e-reader:

[image]

As you can see, the LaTeX in math environments is shrunk to an unreadably small size. I would really like, if possible, to solve this inconvenience. Anyone here has come across the same issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE :) // You can view epub as a series of webpages, with some extra information to organize access. You can reagard eBook-readers as browsers ... with all their variety. There is no guarantee, that two different browsers display the same content in the same way. // To achieve uniformity, avoid epub and distribute pdf. Or accept varaitions of all kind from epub: it's similar, not identical. // Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: how are you encoding the math? as a bitmap image or as svg or something else?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know. I haven't made the file.

Comment: is the file made with tex at all? If you did not make the file, what is your tex question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I own several epub files with mathematical formulas which I assume were written in LaTeX/TeX. I don't know how the math is encoded or displayed. My question is simply as stated above, namely, if there is a way to 'fix' the size of such formulas as they are displayed on my e-reader. I understand this may not be a typical question for this site and I apologize if it should belong elsewhere.

Comment: without knowing anything about how the math is encoded or if it's tex related at all then not really possible to answer (or rather the only answer will be"no" I think) I don't think it's on topic unless you have the tex source and are asking how to regenerate it. You can't assume it's tex just because it has math in it.